# Using Graph To Add and Release IN Receipts

Tags: acumatica

I have created a new screen/page that has an action to create and release an IN Receipt of a serial tracked item.  My action seems to create the document and details including the serial specifications ok.

The issue i am having now is that when i try to release the receipt by using the release.press, it complains that the status is not correct to release. I added code to set the Hold to false but it still is failing. Not sure if i need to do anything else - i was expecting that it would act the same as when you uncheck the Hold checkbox.

I wanted to be sure this is the recommended way to create docs in the system and to release them. I also wasn't sure if there was a way to check for suspended or partially released results.

Here is the Action code on my graph:

```
         public PXAction<usrEdition> AddItems;
         [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Add Items")]
         [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
         protected void addItems()
         {
             String mySer = "";

                 INReceiptEntry myRcptEntry = INReceiptEntry.CreateInstance<INReceiptEntry>();
                 INRegister myINReg = new INRegister();
                 myINReg.TranDesc = "Edition Creation";
                 myINReg.DocType = "R";
                 myINReg.ControlQty = this.Edition.Current.Limit;
                 myINReg.ControlCost = 0;
                 myINReg.ControlAmount = 0;
                 myRcptEntry.receipt.Insert(myINReg);

                 //Add 1 detail line
                 INTran myINTran = new INTran();
                 myINTran.SiteID = 5;
                 myINTran.InventoryID = this.Edition.Current.InventoryID;
                 myINTran.UOM = "PIECE";
                 myINTran.Qty = this.Edition.Current.Limit;

                 myINTran.TranAmt = 0;
                 myINTran.TranDesc = "Edition Creation";
                 myINTran.RefNbr = myRcptEntry.receipt.Current.RefNbr;
                 myINTran.DocType = "R";
                 myINTran.InvtMult = 1;
                 myINTran.UnitCost = 0;

                 myRcptEntry.transactions.Insert(myINTran);

                 for (int i = 1; i <= this.Edition.Current.Limit; i++)
                 {
                     mySer = this.Edition.Current.EditionType.ToString() + i.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
                     INTranSplit mySplit = new INTranSplit();
                     mySplit.InventoryID = this.Edition.Current.InventoryID;
                     mySplit.LotSerialNbr = mySer;
                     mySplit.Qty = 1;
                     mySplit.RefNbr = myRcptEntry.receipt.Current.RefNbr;
                     mySplit.DocType = "R";
                     mySplit.SiteID = 5;
                     mySplit.InvtMult = 1;
                     mySplit.UOM = "PIECE";
                     myRcptEntry.splits.Insert(mySplit);

                 }
                 myINReg.Hold = false;
                 myRcptEntry.Save.Press();
                 myRcptEntry.release.Press();

         }
        #endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set Hold to false but do not update the record inside the graph. This explains why the system complains on the status when you try to release. Furthermore, you should retrieve the result of the Insert() call and use the updated version that is returned to update it. Finally, I don't think you need to set the DocType - it will be defaulted for you.

Updated code sample:

```
    public PXAction<SOOrder> AddItems;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Add Items")]
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    protected void addItems()
    {
        INReceiptEntry myRcptEntry = INReceiptEntry.CreateInstance<INReceiptEntry>();
        INRegister myINReg = new INRegister();
        myINReg.TranDesc = "Sample Inventory Receipt";
        myINReg = myRcptEntry.receipt.Insert(myINReg);

        //TODO: Add your detail lines here

        myINReg.Hold = false;
        myINReg = myRcptEntry.receipt.Update(myINReg);
        myRcptEntry.Save.Press();
        myRcptEntry.release.Press();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly! I was mistakenly thinking that the Save would force the Update.